# what happens at the end of kaliyugas in other mahayugas?

Tags: kali-yuga, kalki, krita-yuga

in the present mahayuga at the end kalki will come to establish righteousness and transform from kaliyuga to satyuga.

but this incarnation of lord Vishnu is only for this time.

how is the transition happening in the other mahayugas?

who kills demons and mlechchas in the end of kaliyuga for other mahayugas?
are there different many kalkis or just one in a kalpa?

plz clarify my doubts.

Comment: Previous Kalki avatar happened as well in prior Kaliyugas